# Create a new column that has value 1 for the top x values in each group and 0 for the rest of the values in the group

Tags: r, group-by, slice, dplyr

```
group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
x <- c(91, 49, 23, 86, 98, 25, 40, 78, 12, 26, 94, 73, 64, 71, 45, 93)

df <- data.frame(group, x)
```

With dyplr, I would like to create a new column (top_x) that has value 1 for the top 3 values in each group and 0 for the rest of the values in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(top_x = as.integer(dense_rank(-x) %in% 1:3)) %>%
  ungroup

#   group     x  rank
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1    91     1
# 2     1    49     0
# 3     1    23     0
# 4     1    86     1
# 5     1    98     1
# 6     2    25     1
# 7     2    40     1
# 8     2    78     1
# 9     2    12     0
#10     3    26     0
#11     3    94     1
#12     3    73     1
#13     3    64     0
#14     3    71     0
#15     3    45     0
#16     3    93     1
```